# Sub-clock FPGA delays on output line

Tags: discrete-signals, algorithms

I am trying to include the ability to have sub-clock delays on an FPGA system's data bus without the need of fractional delay filters.  I am using a Xilinx V6 part, and could utilize its IODELAYE1 instance, but the max delay it can create is less than half a period, and the parts cannot be cascaded.

Is there theory for how to to do sub clock delays of data buses within a system?

Comment: What do you mean by "delay?" Are you wanting to add fractional-sample delay to a digitized signal that you're communicating over that bus? Or do you need some absolute time delay applied to the actual signalling that occurs on the bus lines? Those are two very different problems, and from glancing at [Xilinx's documentation](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug361.pdf), I'm still not sure which the IODELAYE1 module is supposed to do.

Comment: @JasonR I am sampling a signal, attenuating it, delaying it in a buffer, and outputting it out a DAC.  The FPGA is running at 200MHz, so I have 5ns step delays.  I am trying to find a way to delay a signal by .1ns (for instance), without resorting to fractional delay filters.

Comment: What is the purpose of inserting this delay? What is the expected result of the all process?

Comment: @Moti, I am attempting to add a delay-line into a signal path (think multipath).

Comment: Any delay will suffice? What is the limit of an external clock rate you may use with the FPGA? What resolution of a variable delay is desired?

Comment: @Moti I am sort of fixed with a 200MHz clock rate on the FPGA.  The delay would be variable depending on changing a variable while running.  I guess I am open to the resolution depending on what is possible.  But since the current resolution is 5ns delays, I like to see 1ns sub-delays or would love 0.1ns delays.

Comment: You might be able to use existing gates of the FPGA to create a delay of the 200 MHz clock (two invertors cascaded delay will be the resolution).

Comment: How much delay does an inverter inject?

Comment: Look at the FPGA specification. I believe it will be in the sub nano level.